# Condition for inserting an object in HashSet?

Tags: java, collections, hash, hashset

*Please bear with me as i am trying to introduce a new concept in direct contradiction with many active threads.*

What is the condition for inserting an object in HashSet?

Looking at the source code, it zeroes in to :

```
if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
```

Full code at: [HashSet.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.put%28java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object%29)

So, it depends upon

1. Hashcode
2. equals()
3. == i.e if they are same objects.

Now, we know that hashcode of two objects has to be same if obj1.equals(obj2) returns true. Based on the relative values of these 3 parameters i have created the following table :
[image: HashCode adding condition]

Look at condition no. 4. Despite equals() returns false the object gets added to the HashSet. In all the other cases the object simply gets added if and only if equals() returns false. So, one could say  (ignoring condition number 4) that the decision whether an object will be added to the HashSet or not is taken simply by the equals() method. On being asked why do we use hashCode() the standard reply is that it improves the performance by simply comparing integers as the short-circuit operator saves the  execution of equals() method. This argument is discussed in many threads like [Why do we check hash if we are going to check equals anyways?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354754/why-do-we-check-hash-if-we-are-going-to-check-equals-anyways)

However, i find this argument to be incorrect. Hashcode actually has a decision to take if equals() returns false and == returns true. It's highly unlikely because same object usually return true for equals(), until someone explicitly (violating the equals() contract) overrides the equals method such that it returns different values for same object. Still, its a possibility and java appears to be providing a risk management in case of some defaulter code. Your take !

Comment: Wait on condition 4 and 5; == is true but .equals is false?! Under these conditions only madness can exist

Comment: Does the equals method for 4 return random results or what?

Comment: @RichardTingle : Please read the last para. It is possible if you override the equals() method incorrectly.

Comment: Your table is incorrect for S.No. 5.  That is not possible with a correct implementatino of hashCode and equals()

Comment: You can do lots of thing, similarly you can create an invalid hashcode which does not conform to the equals method. You can't expect reasonable results if you do and certainly should never do this

Comment: Looking at it again, your table is just wrong.

Comment: @MadConan qualtar is assuming you can impliment completely invalid .hashCode and .equals() methods

Comment: @RichardTingle: of course but java provides a kind of 'risk management' for that and more importantly hashcode() is not just for performance.

Comment: @RichardTingle:  Seems pretty obvious that if you write a bogus equals/hashCode then you get bogus results.

Comment: @MadConan No argument here

Comment: @qualtar Are there any examples where the `==` `.equals()` `.hashcode` contract isn't violated where `.hashcode()` is not only for performance? Because where that contact is violated anything is allowed to do anything.

Comment: @iberbeu : check the if condition again...

Comment: @RichardTingle : of course . You can write a piece of code where you use hashcode only for comparison. Nothing to do with performance there. However, in this condition hashcode is there for a decision not for some optimization.

Comment: @qualtar your argument is weak as line 5 has the same problem - broken equals contract, but using `hashcode` doesn't help

Comment: It is there for efficiency, its the first condition in the if because its easiest. The fact that it has secondary behaviour if you violate the contact is irrelevant. That secondary behaviour should never be seen so is not considered

Comment: @RomanKonoval: Please read the last para. I agree that its a weak case , nonetheless hashcode() makes a decision, so it is not only for performance optimization....

Comment: It does not make a decision **when the program is in a valid state**

Comment: OP, so essentially you've determined that if the program is completely broken spurious results will happen. What did you expect? It to function correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
```

`e.hash == hash` is present in this condition for reasons of efficiency, it is (under sane circumstances) the quickest test to perform and is used to discount equality at the first hurdle. In all cases where the program is in a valid state (not violating the `==` `.equals()` `.hashCode()` contract) it has no logical effect on the end result of the if statement.

Conditions which are a result of breaking the `==` `.equals()` `.hashCode()` contract are not considered because such a program is in an invalid state and behaviour is not defined. Effects under a broken contract are likely to change from implimentation to implimentation and so should never be relied upon.

Comment: oki....hands down.....SO IF CONTRACT IS BROKEN THERE IS NOT POINT OF COMPARISON AND HASHCODE IS THERE ONLY AND ONLY FOR PERFORMANCE...right???

Comment: Indeed, if the contract is broken you rewrite your program so it isn't. I suppose how a buggy program is buggy can be interesting on on an academic level, but such a program should never make it into production

Answer (score 4):

`HashSet` requires that objects passed to it obey the contract for `hashCode` and `equals` — if they don't, then garbage-in-garbage-out. The contract for `equals` states that if two references are `==`, they must be equal. So your condition 4 above is one that violates the contract for equality, and thus violates the contract for `HashSet`, and thus `HashSet` isn't obligated to act meaningfully when presented such a set of conditions.

Condition 5 also breaks the contract.

Comment: "Isn't obligated to" is not the same as "is obligated not to." It means you're at the mercy of implementation details that can change on a whim.

Comment: @qualtar Having an effect != having a meaningful effect. Its just noise from a broken system

Answer (score 2):

## Contract of `equals()`

If two references are equal or same (==), then `equals()` should return true.

## Contract of `hashCode()`

If `equals()` method return `true` for two objects, then `hashCode()` also needs to return the same hash value for those two objects.

## Truth table

So let's consider the truth-table of 8 scenarios, and there are only 4 valid scenarios as shown below.

```
| hashCode() | equals() |   ==   | add() |
| not-same   | false    | false  | true  |
| not-same   | false    | true   |   -   | - INVALID scenario (== vs equals)
| not-same   | true     | false  |   -   | - INVALID scenario (hash vs equals)
| not-same   | true     | true   |   -   | - INVALID scenario (hash vs equals)
| same       | false    | false  | true  |
| same       | false    | true   |   -   | - INVALID scenario (== vs equals)
| same       | true     | false  | false | 
| same       | true     | true   | false |
```

In the table of the question; S.No 4 & 5 are invalid due to `==` vs `equals()` contract.

Answer (score 1):

Your truth table is incomplete. It should have eight rows, as follows:

```
# HashCode Equals  ==    add()
- -------- ------ ------ -----
1   same     TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
2   same     TRUE FALSE  FALSE
3   same    FALSE FALSE   TRUE
4   diff    FALSE FALSE   TRUE
======= ILLEGAL ROWS =========
5   diff     TRUE  TRUE   TRUE -- Breaks the contract of hashCode, which must
                               -- return the same value on multiple calls
6   diff     TRUE FALSE   TRUE -- Breaks the contract of hashCode
7   same    FALSE  TRUE  FALSE -- Breaks the contract of equals
8   diff    FALSE  TRUE  FALSE -- Breaks the contract of equals
```

Row #5 represents a situation when `hashCode` returns different values when you call it several times (this is an extremely bad thing, but it may occasionally happen when the object is mutable).

Row #6 represents a situation when two equal items have different `hashCode` - a violation of `hashCode` contract.

The last two rows, #7 and #8, are illegal, because they breaks the requirement of `equals()` to be reflexive (i.e. `x.equals(x)` must return `true` for all non-null `x`).

Rows #4 and #5 from your table represent illegal state. `HashSet` would never find out, though, because the first clause of `OR` is a mere optimization. Due to short-circuiting, there would be no call to `equals` when `==` evaluates to `true`, so `HashSet` effectively assumes the reflexivity of `equals`, even if the implementation is wrong.

Comment: i had thought about the entire table. Your line number 1 and 2 are just not required as they point to an obvious fact that if equals() is true hashcode is bound to be same.

Comment: @qualtar Are they, you can write an invalid hashCode such that if equals() is true hashcode is not the same

Comment: @RichardTingle: point...still i cant help overlooking that row 1 and 2 follow equals blindly.

Comment: row 4 is also invalid; if two objects are equals() then the hashCode() values must be same.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't addressing the order of operations.  The real table will include DC (i.e. Don't Care) because they will not be evaluated.

If we add when the following is FALSE

```
if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
```

Then

```
hash==  && (key== || equals()) >> add?
---------------------------------------
   T     |    T    |   DC     ||  F
   F     |    DC   |   DC     ||  T
   T     |    F    |   T      ||  F  <- Not possible with correct code
   T     |    F    |   F      ||  F  <- Not possible with correct code
```

If either the hash or equals functions are incorrect, then none of this matters.

Answer (score 0):

All you need Is Valid condition then you can directly go for this .

```
if(!Obj1.equals(Obj2)) add() ;
```

As you can see there are 8 cases possible , out of which 4 are only valid lets proceed with them .

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ hashCode() ║ equals() ║  ==   ║ add() ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ not-same   ║ false    ║ false ║ true  ║
║ same       ║ false    ║ false ║ true  ║
║ same       ║ true     ║ false ║ false ║
║ same       ║ true     ║ true  ║ false ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

So now its clear we add only when equals() is false .